# Downloading Shapely 1.5 in Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, shapely

I'm looking for Shapely 1.5 for 32 bits Windows 7 but for some reason I'm not authorized to view gohlke's site (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), which is where most entries in stackoverflow point to.

At the moment I've downloaded and installed version 1.4 from pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.4.0#downloads) but would like to upgrade. Pypi does not have the installer of version 1.5 for windows.

Does anybody know of an alternative site?

Comment: I use anaconda's distribution, which I believe also works for Windows. It is a no-hassle way to install Shapely and many other packages besides. (Fiona, PyProj, geos, gdal, etc.)